# Hide Codeigniter error and echo a customized error

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, error-handling

When I try to connect to a database, I get this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user
>   ''@'localhost' to database 'dm_receiver'
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 133
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DataMigrator\ci_my_app\models\Connection_model.php
>   Line: 111 Function: database
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DataMigrator\ci_my_app\models\ReadDatabase_model.php
>   Line: 7 Function: establish
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\DataMigrator\ci_my_app\controllers\Home.php
>   Line: 7 Function: model
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\DataMigrator\index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once
>
> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/DataMigrator/ci_my_app/models/ReadDatabase_model.php
>
> Line Number: 7

I have specified the wrong username on purpose to test what happens when I can't get a database connection. Well, that's what I get. I would like to hide this error and echo my own message if this happens. How do I do that?

**Edit:** Let my ask my question another way. When I use $this->db->get('mytable'); I might get the same error. This could be because either the hostname, database name, username or password is wrong. So how could I find out which one of them is not correct and echo like for example watch out, your database name is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn off error messages in production by editing your `index.php` file:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```

Then use your code to check the conditions of what comes out of your database, or edit `application/errors/error_db.php` to define a custom error page.